# Came across this code & I'm wondering why this static helper method is needed?

Tags: java, file-io, filereader, helpermethods

**I did not write this code**, All credit goes to the person that is hosting the link. So here is a link to the code and the guy who wrote it is listed on github also... Link **[-Github SourceCode-](https://github.com/jrankin2/FileService/blob/master/src/net/datbear/fileservice/impl/TextFileReader.java)**

Here is the method preview: (see class below)

```
//helper method
public static List readFile(String filePath) throws IOException {
    return new TextFileReader(filePath).readFile();
}
```

**Wait a second, I think I may get it now, it's just so someone can invoke the `readFile()` method without having a dependancy to this object, or am I wrong?**

and here is a link to the project on git, if anyone wants a lower level view of the project.
I have searched around and I only see helper methods breaking up larger tasks, which was my initial understanding of them.
However, I was on github, and found this: (method brought up from bottom of page for easy viewing, but is also in the class code. Plus here is a link to the git if anyone wants to take a better look... Thank you for any replies or edits that
looked normal until the static helper method at the bottom of the page

```
public class TextFileReader implements FileReaderStrategy<String> {

private static final FileType FILE_TYPE = FileType.TEXT_FILE;
private String filePath;

public TextFileReader(String filePath) {
    this.filePath = filePath;
}

@Override
public List<String> readFile() throws IOException {
    List lines = new ArrayList();
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(filePath));
        String line = in.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            lines.add(line);
            line = in.readLine();
        }
    } catch(IOException ioe){
        throw ioe;
    }finally{
        if(in != null){
            in.close();
        }
    }
    
    return lines;
}

//helper method
public static List readFile(String filePath) throws IOException {
    return new TextFileReader(filePath).readFile();
}
```

}

Comment: If you ask me, without making the constructor private, I dont see any use in it. It creates a new object and invokes the method from it, something you could manually do, seeing how the constructor and the method are both public. Thats just my opinion though. I guess the fact that it returns List, and the only purpose of that class is to read a file. In this case, maybe its justified to create a new object any time you wanna call the method. Although, the public constructor kind of voids that theory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  Although I would say that it's so the method can be called on the `Class` rather than on an object, or instance, of the class.

For example, static methods can be called like this:

```
TextFileReader.readFile(<filepath>);
```

without having to first create an instance of the class.